# Quick way to view and manipulate kafka stored data? #isoBlue #isoBus

Tags: apache-kafka

In the quickest and easiest way, I want binary data in Kafka message logs viewable as hex string values.

I have the following data that contains CAN messages as binary, and I want to view it as hex strings

```
case-8010-wheat-ault-072018/
├── cleaner-offset-checkpoint
├── debug-0
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.index
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.log
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.timeindex
│   ├── 00000000000000006972.index
│   ├── 00000000000000006972.log
│   ├── 00000000000000006972.snapshot
│   ├── 00000000000000006972.timeindex
│   ├── 00000000000000079766.snapshot
│   └── leader-epoch-checkpoint
├── gps-0
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.index
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.log
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.timeindex
│   ├── 00000000000000003235.index
│   ├── 00000000000000003235.log
│   ├── 00000000000000003235.snapshot
│   ├── 00000000000000003235.timeindex
│   ├── 00000000000000029657.snapshot
│   └── leader-epoch-checkpoint
├── imp-0
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.index
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.log
│   ├── 00000000000000000000.timeindex
│   ├── 00000000000000004940.index
│   ├── 00000000000000004940.log
│   ├── 00000000000000004940.snapshot
│   ├── 00000000000000004940.timeindex
│   ├── 00000000000000915321.snapshot
│   └── leader-epoch-checkpoint
```

The data source provides docs for consuming the data, but possibly due to version miss-match, using kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1.tgz the steps fail. https://www.isoblue.org/docs/data/data/

Trying to view the data directly, I have:

**1.** Played with kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments

```
./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --deep-iteration --print-data-log  --files ../../case-8010-wheat-ault-072018/imp-0/00000000000000004940.log | head -n 15
```

I tried to manipulate the DumpLogSegments output, but the data doesn't look as expected.`./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --deep-iteration --print-data-log --files ../../case-8010-wheat-ault-072018/imp-0/00000000000000004940.log | awk -F'payload:' '{print $2}' | awk -F'offset:' '{print $1}' | od -A n -t x1 | head -n 10`

**2.** I am currently trying to write a file source connector based on: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html#connector-example

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do here? Are you wanting to consume data from Kafka, or to access the underlying storage? And how Kafka Connect figures into what you're wanting to do

Comment: I want what kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments lets me do, but I want to manipulate the payload so it's human readable; I want the binary payload displayed as a hexstring.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get a KafkaConsumer to work with Python2 Kafka. The isoBlue scripts did not work for me.

**1.** edit $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
`log.dirs=<KAFKA_DATA>`

**2.** zookeeper-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties

**3.** kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

**4.** kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties

**5.** Using Python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import sys

try:

    bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092']
    topicName = 'tra'
    consumer = KafkaConsumer (topicName, group_id = 'can-test',bootstrap_servers = bootstrap_servers,auto_offset_reset='earliest');

    for message in consumer:
        wait = input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.")    
        print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,message.offset, message.key,message.value))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

**6.** It really helped me to watch if the server was running and if the data was still there.

```
watch -n 5 ls -alF <KAFKA_DATA> | head
watch -n 5 netstat -a | grep 9092
```

Comment: Hi Christian, i'm trying to read the log data from isoblue as well, did you succeed? i'm interested to know all your detailed steps.

Comment: Hi @agenis. I did manage to read some data, but not all of it. I don't know much about kafka and I was trying to avoid having to learn it. I will probably will come back to this as I want to see a deviceDescriptor binary data transfer. It seems that kafka deletes the logs as it runs (note step #6). The above steps worked, but I didn't get all the records; ~5000 records and none of it was J11783. Feel free to DM if you want to talk about isobus.